# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{s^a + 1}$ with $0 < a \leq 1$

Tags: laplace-transform

### Problem

I am looking for the following inverse Laplace transform,
$$
f(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s^a + 1}\right] 
\;\;\;\;\; 
\text{with}
\;\;\;\;\;
0 < a \leq 1.
$$

### What I understand

- with $a = 1$, $f(t) = e^{-t}$
- for small $t \ll 1$, $f(t)$ should behave
  $$
  f(t)\approx \frac{1}{\Gamma(a)} t^{a-1}
  $$
  as
  $$
  \frac{1}{s^a + 1} \approx s^{-a}
  $$
  with large $s\gg 1$
- for large $t \gg 1$, $f(t)$ should behave
  $$
  f(t) \approx \frac{a}{\Gamma(1-a)} t^{-(a+1)}
  $$
  from
  $$
  t f(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{a s^{a-1}}{(s^a + 1)^2}\right] 
  \approx \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[a s^{a-1}\right]
  $$
  with small $s \ll 1$.

### Numerical solution

I have a master equation for $f(t)$ and the above Laplace transform is obtained from this master equation.
By numerically solving the master equation, I obtained the following numerical solution,
[image]

But I want an analytical representation (even an approximated one), not the numerical solution.

### Candidates?

Since the solution may smoothly connect between these two limit forms, and should be similar to the exponential function if $a\approx 1$, I expected something similar to the kappa distribution,
$t^{a-1}\left(1 + \frac{t}{a+1}\right)^{-(a+1)}$.
However, the exponent does not match, and this does not reproduce both the Laplace transform and the numerical solution.

Wolfram alpha does not give a solution, either.

Any idea would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: On page 207 [this](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9781119393351.app3) table states that the Inverse Laplace-Transform of $\frac{1}{s^\alpha+1}$ is $$t^{\alpha-1}\mathscr E_{\alpha,\alpha}^1(-t^\alpha),$$ where $\mathscr E$ denotes the Mittag-Leffler function.

Comment: @vitamin d  Thank you! This is what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @[vitamin](https://mathoverflow.net/users/175826/vitamin-d) pointed out, the distribution having the Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{1 + s^\alpha}$ is called [Mittag-Leffler distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_distribution).

Although there are no known closed forms, many of its properties are investigated, such as its exponential-mixture representation [1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167715297001673),
$$
f(x; \alpha) = \frac{\sin(\pi \alpha)}{\pi}
\int_0^\infty 
\frac{1}{\beta}\;
e^{-x/\beta}\;
\frac{\beta^\alpha}{1 + \beta^{2\alpha} + 2\beta^\alpha \cos(\pi \alpha)} 
\; d\beta
$$